# New to WPF Data Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I'm new to WPF Data binding, and a bit stuck.
Apparently my textbox is not correctly bound to the data element I intend, and I cannot figure out why.

First in my `MainWindow.xaml` file, I declare an object:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:Aircraft x:Key="Aircraft"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

This creates an object of type Aircraft during `MainWindow.InitializeComponent()`
(I can verify this by putting a breakpoint on the constructor of Aircraft)

Class `Aircraft` is defined in a `.cs` file, with property `Pilot` which has property `Weight`, so that `myAircraft.Pilot.Weight` is an `int`.

Next, I try to bind a textbox to this property:

```
<TextBox Name="PICWeight" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Aircraft}, Path=Pilot.Weight}" />
```

The application compiles and runs, but when I put numeric text into the textbox, then move the focus to another textbox, I expect to see the `setter` for `Pilot.Weight` get called (I have a breakpoint on it).   It doesn't.

I believe that there should be a default ValueConverter from String (from the textbox) to int (the type of the Weight property), and that textboxes should have default update-source event of `LostFocus`.

Am I specifying the binding properly?
Do I need to create a ValueConverter, or explicitly specify the update event?
Is there anything else I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to bind the Text property, not just DataContext, like:

```
<TextBox Name="PICWeight" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Aircraft}}" Text="{Binding Path=Pilot.Weight}" />
```

or:

```
<TextBox Name="PICWeight" Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource Aircraft}, Path=Pilot.Weight}" />
```