# How does DataGrid bind to properties of any collection?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid

I am making a WPF user control and I want similar behavior as DataGrid control in sense of binding. My question is: How does DataGrid know how to bind to any collection of type IEnumerable? For example: You can pass a DataView as ItemsSource, and you can also pass any object collection. How DataGrid decides whether to bind to a column of DataView, or to a property of object only by looking at this:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding **Path=SomePropertyOrColumn**}"/>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5488014/in-wpf-are-binding-path-and-binding-really-equal, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504480/when-to-use-path-in-wpf-binding and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742449/new-to-wpf-data-binding

Comment: @Sandeep G B That was not my question. I know how to do binding, I want to know how does DataGrid do it internaly with any object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a complex area; the following is a breakdown from winforms binding, but I understand that WPF binding isn't that different;

- given an object, the first thing binding code will do is look for `IListSource` - and if so use `GetList()` to get the actual binding (this is how a data-table becomes a data-view for binding purposes)
- after that, the source is typically checked for `ITypedList`; this acts as a flexible way of obtaining pseudo-properties (`GetItemProperties()`) represented by the model; data-view implements `ITypedList`, creating pseudo-properties per instance
- otherwise, it might be possible to identify an obvious type for the data, which can mean:

  - looking for an indexer of the form `public SomeType this[int index] {get;}` - note that most collections will satisfy this
  - (not done by winforms, but might be for WPF) resolving via reflection the `T` in either `IList<T>` or `IEnumerable<T>` if the object implements those interfaces
  - taking the first object (if any) from the sorce, and using `GetType()`
- once a type is known, `TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(type)` can be used to obtain properties; in many cases this will be via reflection, but it is also possible to add an indirection layer (via `TypeDescriptionProvider`) to supply properties for a type (this can be added at runtime, which can be very convenient)
- in the case of individual binding (not list binding), there is also `TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(obj)` - in addition to reflection and `TypeDescriptionProvider`, this also has support for `ICustomTypeDescriptor` which can be implemented by an individual object to supply custom properties at runtime (very similar to `TypeDescriptionProvider`, but with the individual object taking responsibility for the properties)

I don't know exactly how much of this applies to WPF binding, but I'm pretty sure the `IListSource` and `ITypedList` processing is identical. From memory, most (all?) of the winforms strategies will work on WPF - so it could be that and changes are *additional* hooks.

Comment: Thanks, your answer gave me the idea how to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

**I think that**:

you can get `Type` of element of its `Collection`, this type `Type` have [GetProperties()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aky14axb.aspx) method, which returns all public properties available in its type, and, after its know all public properties, it can bind with them.

Comment: Yes, but how does it work with DataView? It is a collection of DataRowView objects, and those objects do not have Column property, and they are still binded to columns.

Comment: I think that this article should help [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb669099(v=VS.100).aspx). Field<Type>(string) - may be you search this?